# The path of minimum time difference in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Suppose there are two points A and B in the inertial reference frame S. Suppose traveler x started from point A and travelled to point B. In reference frame S, it took traveler x an amount of time, T, to take the journey. But in the reference frame of traveler x, it clearly took less amount of time as it is moving and time supposedly dilates. Take these two time and substract them, we call it the time difference. An extreme case is where traveler x moves at the speed of light. So in the reference frame S, we see that the journey took time (rB-rA)/c while no time has passed for the traveler, so the time difference is (rB-rA)/c. My question is, what is the path in phase space (for clearly we can vary the velocity along the way) such that this entity time difference is at a minimum?

P.S. my guess is that it is the case when the traveler moves at infinitesimally small speed for an infinite amount of time.

Comment: What is the minimum positive real number?

Comment: @WillO $\text d x$

Comment: @AaronStevens :  :)